# getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'friends' of undefined when using custom directive in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I can really use some help here. I have 2 custom directives (second one nested in 1st). All the code is running fine except the second directive. When I try to click on Remove button, I get the following error in Dev tools:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'friends' of undefined
    at vm.removeFriend
```

I have tried everything and at my wits end but can't figure this out. Can someone assist please? Here is the Plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/jmIifQPPO7Xmiw6rVTnM

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>


<script src="script.js"></script>

<script src="mainController.js"></script>
<script src="userInfoCard.js"></script>
 <script src="removeFriend.js"></script>
```

```
<aa-user-info-card user="vm.user"> </aa-user-info-card>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this plunker you can delete a friend, but I don't know if this is the kind of solution you are looking for.

https://plnkr.co/edit/T8moxHdbVxF9vtOfFAa5?p=preview

In userInfo.html I've changed this lines:

```
<div ng-init='user = vm.user'>
   <aa-remove-friend ></aa-remove-friend>
</div>
```

And in removeFriend.js changed this:

```
var idx = $scope.user.friends.indexOf(friend);
if (idx > -1) {
   $scope.user.friends.splice(idx, 1);
}
```

I hope this helps.

Regards

Comment: aha. This makes complete sense. Especially, $scope instead of vm, as I was corrupting the scope and you maintained it. I didn't know you could use both $scope and vm at the same time. Thanks so much for your help!! What I am curious about is if I am getting user object from $scope and the removeFriend.js directive is inheriting from the parent, why did you need to do an ng-init?

Comment: Hi! The truth is I didn't find any other way of sending the user from the outer scope to the inner scope. I think if you send everthing as a parameter in aa-user-info-card, you can do it to, but you should send friend as a parameter too.